# How to Conditionally reverse a list with in a compareBy in Kotlin

Tags: sorting, dictionary, kotlin, functional-programming, conditional-statements

I have the following code

```
    val sortMethod = compareBy<Item> {
        when (model.preferences.getSortMethod()) {
            TITLE -> it.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
            DATE -> it.getSortableDateString()
            AUTHOR -> it.getAuthor().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
            DATE_ADDED -> it.getSortableDateAddedString()
        }
    }.thenBy { it.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()) }
```

which i then use on Lists like so

`myItems.sortedWith(sortMethod)`

I like this solution and I think it's very elegant. However, **i would like to add the ability to sort ascendingly/descendingly as well**.

So I am asking how do I add a conditional `.reverse()` to my sortMethod? I am very reluctant to put a if condition on every one of my sort calls and would like to get it all done in the sortMethod logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
list.sortedWith(if (sortAscending) sortMethod else sortMethod.reversed())
```

---

I suggest removing `Locale.getDefault()` since `toLowerCase()` is equivalent to `toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())`.

Comment: thank you, this is what i wanted. Android studio's linter gives me a warning and suggests I add Locale.getDefault() to my toLowerCase though?

Comment: @mickstar Calling `toLowerCase()` calls `toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())`, so manual specification of `Locale.getDefault()` doesn't make any sense. You should use `toLowerCase()` without an argument for creating a result that will be displayed. But if you use a result internally, for example, for sorting database entries, you should specify a **constant** locale (not `Locale.getDefault()`), or your program may break after default locale changing. If you don't know where a result will be used, you should extract the `locale` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I have changed it to Locale.ROOT. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun List<Item>.sort() : List<Item>{
    if (model.preferences.isSortedAscendingly()){
        return this.sortedWith(sortMethod)
    }
    return this.sortedWith(sortMethod).reversed()
}
```

Decided my solution will be using the above extension function, but if anyone has a better way i would love to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Use `let()`?

```
private fun List<Item>.sort() = sortedWith(sortMethod).let {
    if (model.preferences.isSortedAscendingly())
        it
    else
        it.reversed()
}
```